# A very large undirected graph computes the shortest path of all vertices. How to improve efficiency? Can it be split and combined?

Tags: java, shortest-path, jgrapht

Now there is a very large undirected graph network, I want to calculate the shortest path between all the vertices of the undirected graph, but the efficiency is very low, can I split and merge the undirected graph? The Java library currently in use is **jgrapht**. At present, the number of vertices is 8000+, and the consumption of memory and calculation time is very serious.

```
DijkstraManyToManyShortestPaths<V, E> manyShortestPaths = new DijkstraManyToManyShortestPaths<>(graph);
ManyToManyShortestPathsAlgorithm.ManyToManyShortestPaths<V, E> shortestPaths = manyShortestPaths.getManyToManyPaths(vs, vs);
```

Comment: Just mentioning the number of vertices is not very useful: computing a shortest path on a graph with 8000 vertices, and no edges, is a pretty simple task :). Depending on the number of edges (dense or sparse graph) you might want to choose a different algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Using JGraphT, you could try the following 2 different algorithms:

1. [ContractionHierarchyBidirectionalDijkstra](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org.jgrapht.core/org/jgrapht/alg/shortestpath/ContractionHierarchyBidirectionalDijkstra.html) which relies on contraction hierarchies
2. [TransitNodeRoutingShortestPath](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org.jgrapht.core/org/jgrapht/alg/shortestpath/TransitNodeRoutingShortestPath.html) which uses transit nodes

Both algorithms require a fair amount of precomputing. But once precomputing completes, performing shortest path queries becomes cheap. You can try both, as they implement the same shortest path interface.

To further optimize memory storage, you could also have a look at some of the specialized graph data structures in the jgrapht-opt package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's a dense graph, Can you provide code examples?